# Finding the limit at infinity of $f(z) = \frac{\overline{z}}{|z|^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I would like to make sure I'm doing everything right and not missing anything, since I know that some familiar functions do crazy things in the complex setting.

Since $|z|^2 = \overline{z}z$ I simplified my function to $\frac{1}{z}$.

Then if I take the limit as $z$ tends to infinity I get zero.  So the limit of $f(z)$ is also zero.  Does this seem legit?  Also, would anything be different if the numerator of $f(z)$ was simply $z$?

Comment: It is fine. If we replace the numerator by $z$, nothing really changes.

Answer (score 0):

Your evaluation of the limit is correct. It may help you to think of the modulus: as long as $|f(z)|$ tends to zero as $|z|$ tends to infinity, $f(z)$ tends to zero as well.